# C# cannot convert 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#

I'm new with C# how can I fix the issue? The error is showing at the last line(query). Any help is appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace file
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var hobbies = new List<string>() { };
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name");
            string myName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Tell me something about you");
            string myAbout = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("What kind of hobbies do you have?");
            string myHobbies = Console.ReadLine();
            hobbies.Add(myHobbies);
            var query = myName + '\n' + myAbout + '\n' + myHobbies;
            File.AppendAllLines("C:\\test.txt", query);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `File.AppendAllLines("C:\\test.txt", new string []{query});` will do (`string[]` implements `IEnumerable<string>`)

Answer (score 5):

As states in the docs for [`File.AppendAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines?view=net-5.0), the method signature is

```
public static void AppendAllLines (string path, 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> contents);
```

i.e. the second argument is expected to be an `IEnumerable<String>` and you are passing `query`, which is a `String`. You probably want [`AppendAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=net-5.0), which receives a String in the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

The method expects a collection of strings as second parameter, but you provide only a string. You can use File.AppendAllText instead which works with a single string.

```
File.AppendAllText("C:\\test.txt", query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll really get that error since your trying to combine a List into a string.
Just iterate first whats inside of your List in a string that will hold its values before proceeding.

Just like below,

```
        List<string> hobbies = new List<string>();
        string hobbies_ = "";
       


        var hobbies = new List<string>() { };
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name");
        string myName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Tell me something about you");
        string myAbout = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("What kind of hobbies do you have?");
        string myHobbies = Console.ReadLine();
        hobbies.Add(myHobbies);
       

        foreach (var hobby in hobbies)
        {
            hobbies_ += hobbies + "\n";
        }

        var query = myName + '\n' + myAbout + '\n' + hobbies_;
        File.AppendAllLines("C:\\test.txt", query);
```